# Is it possible to recover the actual index of elements in a `std::span`?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, std-span

I have a class with a `std::vector` member variable. I also have a member function that takes a contiguous range in that `std::vector`, specified by two `size_t` parameters, and performs some operations on it.

```cpp
class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> objects;

public:

    void func(size_t start_index, size_t end_index); 
}
```

Now, I want to replace the two `size_t` parameters with a single `std::span` parameter to improve safety, readability, and maintainability. There's one obstacle, however: in my function, I need to be able to recover the first index of the range *in the original `std::vector`*. As in, I need to be able to find where the `std::span` begins in the original array. **Is there a way to do this?** If not, then do I have no choice but to use my original clunky design?

(I initially tried recovering the first index by subtracting `objects.begin()` from the `begin()` iterator of the `std::span` parameter I had, but this resulted in a compilation error.)

Comment: Have you tried `span.data() - vec.data()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the original vector available, then the index in the vector of the first element in the span is

```
auto index = (span.data() - vector.data());
```

---

> (I initially tried recovering the first index by subtracting `objects.begin()` from the `begin()` iterator of the `std::span` parameter I had, but this resulted in a compilation error.)

Thats not going to work. You cannot substract or get the difference between two iterators from different containers. Their `data` on the other hand is pointers to the same array and you can take their difference.

Comment: It may be worth adding `std::ptrdiff_t` as the type instead of keeping it `auto`, for educational purposes.